# link wordpress and stackoverflow

Tags: widgets, stackoverflow

how do i link stackoverflow widget in wordpress to my profile in stackoverflow to show badges, reputaions ??

Answer (score 7):

html:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/flair

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this Plugin right here : [stackoverflow+](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stackoverflow/)
You can find it's Documentation Here: [Stackoverflow+ Documentation](http://techstricks.com/stackoverflow-plus-wordpress-plugin-show-your-stackoverflow-stats/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new widget plugin called [Stackoverflow Profile Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stackoverflow-profile-widget/)